# TypeScript string equality

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've read a lot about string equality in JavaScript and assumed it is the same thing in TypeScript, but I'm puzzled by this problem.
I have two strings that are exactly the same and yet having a non equal result in `==` and `===` operators.

This is the code:

```
                                this.cl_applied_filts.forEach (
                                    filt => {
                                        console.log (`[cl-filts]`);
                                        store.getState()._cl_filters.forEach(
                                            f => {
                                                const af : string = filt.name;
                                                const lf : string = f.name;
                                                let sa : String = new String(af);
                                                let sf : String = new String(lf);
                                                console.log (`[cl-filts] String '${af}' and '${lf}'
equal (af == lf)  ${(af == lf)} not equal (af != lf) ${(af != lf)}
buffers:
applied af ${JSON.stringify(filt)}
           lengths ${filt.name.length} length ${af.length}.
db      lf ${JSON.stringify(f)}
           lengths ${f.name.length} length ${lf.length}.
normalized af '${sa.normalize()}'
           lf '${sf.normalize()}'
`);
                                                let equal : boolean = true;
                                                for (let i = 0; i < af.length; ++i) {
                                                    let afc = sa.charCodeAt(i);
                                                    let lfc = sf.charCodeAt(i);
                                                    if (afc != lfc) {
                                                        console.log (`!!! both nums aren't equal !!!`);
                                                        equal = false;
                                                    }
                                                    console.log (`${i} ${sa.charCodeAt(i)} ${sf.charCodeAt(i)}`);
                                                }
                                                if (equal) {
                                                    console.log (`** both strings are equal **`);
                                                }
                                                if (store.string_eq(filt.name, f.name)) {
                                                    f.checked = true;
                                                    console.log (`[cl-filts] checked ${f.checked}`);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        );
                                    });
```

And this is the Firefox console output:

```
[cl-filts] String 'BURNLEY' and 'BURNLEY'
equal (af == lf)  false not equal (af != lf) true
buffers:
applied af {"checked":true,"name":{"type":"Buffer","data":[66,85,82,78,76,69,89]}}
           lengths 7 length 7.
db      lf {"checked":0,"name":{"type":"Buffer","data":[66,85,82,78,76,69,89]}}
           lengths 7 length 7.
normalized af 'BURNLEY'
           lf 'BURNLEY'
control-lines.component.ts:56:56
0 66 66 control-lines.component.ts:74:60
1 85 85 control-lines.component.ts:74:60
2 82 82 control-lines.component.ts:74:60
3 78 78 control-lines.component.ts:74:60
4 76 76 control-lines.component.ts:74:60
5 69 69 control-lines.component.ts:74:60
6 89 89 control-lines.component.ts:74:60
** both strings are equal ** control-lines.component.ts:77:60
[cl-filts] checked true control-lines.component.ts:81:60
```

The object declaration:

```
export class Filter
{
    checked : boolean = false;
    name : string = '';
}
```

We can see both strings are the same, even to bytes, but they give non-equal result. Why?
`store.string_eq` is a function I've created to compare two strings byte to byte with  `charCodeAt` function to avoid loosing more time with this, but I would like to know what's happening here.

EDIT: I've modified as per the comments to show there is no difference.

Comment: Don't make `new String()` objects. Two objects will never be `==` to each other.

Comment: Also don't use `var`, use `let` for variables whose value you are going to change over the course of the block, and `const` for variables whose value should be only ever be set once for the duration of the block. `var` is a legacy keyword for declaring hoistable, function-scoped variables, not nicely well-behaved block-scoped variables.

Comment: This _is_ the same between JS and TS, `new String("BURNLEY") != new String("BURNLEY")` is a purely runtime comparison.

Comment: They fail with `string` as well. I've used `String` only to be able to use `charCodeAt` function.

Comment: If you wrote proper TypeScript, then `filt.name` and `f.name` are already strings because of the interface or explicit typing you used for those fields. `const af: string = filt.name;` and done.

Comment: I've modified the code to comply with your suggestions, as it was before my investigation, but it still fails.

Comment: @jonrsharpe my first try was with `string`, I've changed to `String` to use `charCodeAt` function, but my original problems was and still is with `string`

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans yep, my object is declared `string` and `const af : string = filt.name` still fails. As said in other comments, this is why I used `String` (*after* the failure), to be able to use `charCodeAt` function and manually check the bytes.

Comment: Still fails _how_? Please talk about what that does in your post, because if `filt.name` really is typed as a string, that assignment _cannot fail_ TSC verification. Also please fix the indentation for the code that's in your post right now. This is not [helping the people you're asking for help](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I don't understand why you have to do `new String()` to use charCodeAt.  This works: `"hello".charCodeAt(3)`

Comment: Look at the section 'string primitives and string objects' [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String).   There is a warning that you should rarely use the string constructor, but you can do it without the 'new' keyword also.  Compare `String('hello') == String('hello')` with `new String('hello') == new String('hello')`

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I've nailed down the problem and it wasn't only about strings.

The `f` object is created from a `bencode` object, from Github library I can't remember.

The `bencode` object gives an object of the form:

`{"checked":true,"name":{"type":"Buffer","data":[66,85,82,78,76,69,89]}`

when accesing `name` property for display, it is converted to a `string`.

The `filt` (type `Filter`) is obtained from a database, and `name` is of type `string`.

When property `name` as `string` *theoretically* in both objects, are compared, they aren't equal.

The problem is the `bencode` object property isn't really converted to `string`.

So, even if `"name":{"type":"Buffer","data":[...]}` is treated as `string` when displayed, and when converted to a `String` object, it isn't converted when comparing, so what hapens is we are comparing:

`{"type":"Buffer","data":[...]} == 'BURNLEY'`

And apparently, assigning one of those `"name":{"type"...` property to a `const string` doesn't really convert it to a `string` either, or it uses a different kind of buffer. It has something that makes them not equal even if they have the same text and are `string`.